# Multiple users authentication with one account in Python Django?

Tags: python, django, account

I want to make an app where ie 5 users can use one account, these users should have different permissions within this account, and one of them should have Admin permissions (create users connected to account, delete users). Which way should I move to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into [Django-Organizations](https://github.com/bennylope/django-organizations)

Comment: Thanks! This is what I looked for!